# Losing variable at Store's Beforeload

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a store that I use three different ways - to search, edit and delete bins from my database.
The store requires a Beforeload variable of bin:

```
BinDetailsStore.on('beforeload', function() {
        BinDetailsStore.getProxy().extraParams = {
            bin: bin
        }
    }, this);
```

From another function I have also been able to bring up the bin details from a successful add of a bin:

```
...
button.up('form').submit({
                            clientValidation: false,
                            url: 'binsites/addbin?bin=' + bin + '&size=' + size + '&bintype=' + bintype + '&stat=' + stat + '&bpid=' + bpid + '&rte=' + rte,
                            success: function() {
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Bin Added', 'Bin ' + bin + ' added');
                                deleteFlag = false;
                                BinDetailsStore.load();

                                popBinAdd.close();
                                popBinAdd = null;
                            }
                        });
```

However when I edit a bin's details and try to reload the store this way

```
...
button.up('form').submit({
                    url: 'binsites/editbin?bid=' + bid + '&size=' + newSize + '&type=' + newType + '&bin=' + bin,
                    success: function() {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Bin Saved', 'Bin ' + bin + ' has been saved');
                        //Ext.Msg.alert(bin);
                        editFlag = false;
                        binEdForm.close();
                        binEdForm = null;
                        BinDetailsStore.load();
                    }
                });
```

The details save and the success call is called but I lose the value of bin by the time the beforeload event is hit.
I have tried redefining bin within the success function and passing bin along to another function to call the load on BinDetailsStore (bin transfers to new function but is again lost for beforeload) to no avail.

Bin is defined as so:

```
BinDetailsStore.on('load', function() {
        if (deleteFlag) {
            bin = null;
            bid = null;
            size = null;
            bintype = null;
            stat = null;
            this.binDelConfirm(bin, bid, size, bintype);
        } else if (editFlag) {
            bin = null;
            bid = null;
            size = null;
            updated = null;
            bintype = null;
            stat = null;
            desc = null;
            this.binEditForm(bin, bid, size, updated, bintype, stat, desc);
        } else {
            this.loadSearchResults();
        }
    }, this);
```

Because the editFlag is active it passes along to binEditForm:

```
binEditForm: function(bin, bid, size, updated,  bintype, stat, descr) {
    if (binEdSer) {
        binEdSer.close();
        binEdSer = null;
    }
    if (binEdForm) {
        binEdForm.close();
        binEdForm = null;
    }
    if (binResult) {
            binResult.destroy();
            binResult = null;
    } 
    if (cusResult) {
        cusResult.destroy();
        cusResult = null;
    }

    if (!bin && !bid && !size && !updated && !bintype && !stat && !desc) {
      if (BinDetailsStore.getTotalCount()) {
        rec = BinDetailsStore.getAt(0);

        bin = rec.get('number');
        bid = rec.get('id_');
        size = rec.get('size');
        updated = rec.get('updated');
        bintype = rec.get('bintype');
        if (rec.get('cust_type') == 'Park' || rec.get('cust_type') == 'Truck') {
                stat = rec.get('cust_type') + ' - ' + rec.get('park');
            } else {
                stat = rec.get('cust_type');
            }
        desc = rec.get('desc_');
      }
    }
```

In short I would like to know why the value of bin disappears when the BinDetailsStore beforeload event gets fired.

Thank you for your time and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is really unclear, not really sure what the question is here.

Comment: Sorry - I'm losing the value of bin when I call BinDetailsStore.load(). I want to know why that might be.

Comment: Because you're overwriting it somewhere. You'll need to trace your code and figure it out. Without being able to run it nobody is going to tell you.

Comment: I have tested bin in the success call where it still had its value and then before I set the extra parameters in the beforeload where the value was null. Placing breaks on the code in Chrome shows the value turn null as soon as it exits the success call into ext-all code before coming to my beforeload to get the extra params. As far as I can tell I'm not the one overwriting my variable.